# How to get GOTEK to work with CDTV?

Tags: emulation, commodore, floppy-drive, amiga-cdtv

I'm trying to connect Gotek drive to my CDTV using external caddy (amitek).

The drive has 3 digit LED display, after boot i can see F-F. When I insert Flash drive it detects images on it, I can navigate to a specific one, but the software doesn't start.

CD activity led flashes, but Gotek's activity led doesn't flash on start, nor indicating it's trying to read image when one is selected.

I have jumper on S0, tried with FF.CFG and without (firmware: FlashFloppy 2.13, working on A1200). Can't get it to boot from it.

Do I need any specific kickstart and mod to swap it as I find fit?

[image]

Comment: Have you installed firmware on your Gotek? Which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires a slight wire / connector mod:

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/oldcrap.org/2017/11/17/gotek-in-an-external-amiga-drive-closure/amp/